# Problems in customizing Twitter feed using java script in Hugo

Tags: java, html, twitter, hugo

I found the following code to embed a twitter feed with customization options into my html code of Hugo Academic (https://gist.github.com/mpukit/423cfb4e5d073288e10d34d4c73ba37d)
I went ahead and put this code in the html file ("pages.html") and the twitter Blog appears. However, the java script is not rendered which contains all customization options. I also tried to use type="application/javascript", but this does not work either. Does someone have an idea why it is not working?

```
<!-- Twitter Embed Code -->
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/USERNAME"-
data-chrome="noheader nofooter noborders transparent noscrollbar"-
data-tweet-limit="4" dnt="true">Tweets by USERNAME</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- / Twitter Embed Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mpukit/423cfb4e5d073288e10d34d4c73ba37d/raw/b63b66341f44c148642a6c3c0c2268d539fd0878/twitter-override.js"></script>
```